# Problema de recursividad, punteros y cadenas en c

Tags: c

se busca crear un programa recursivo y con punteros que reciba dos cadenas ‘S’ y ‘X’. Cada elemento de la cadena ‘X’ se busca en ‘S’, y de encontrarse una ocurrencia, debe eliminarse de esta última

Soy nuevo ocupando recursividad y estoy un tanto confundido con este ejercicio de una guía, ¿como sería el codigo de este problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow! Te invito a [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). No puedes venir a esta comunidad y decir: "Como seria el codigo de este problema?", aqui no hacemos tareas o deberes, aqui resolvemos dudas especificas orientado a un problema. En la pregunta debe ir [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fuente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void reduce_rec( int buff[], char *s, char *out ) {
  
  if ( *s == 0 ) { *out=0; return; }

  if ( buff[*s] ) {
    buff[*s]--;
  } else {
    *out++= *s;
  }

  reduce_rec( buff, ++s, out );
}

char *reduce( char *x, char *s ) {

  if ( !x || !s ) return NULL;

  int buff[255] = {0};
  int len;
  char *out;

  len = strlen(s);
  out = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)*(len+1) );

  // rellenamos la tabla buff
  while ( *x ) buff[*x++]++;

  // iniciamos la rutina recursiva
  reduce_rec( buff, s, out );

  return out;
}

int main() {
  char *out = reduce( "a", "casa" );
  printf( "%s\n", out );
  free( out );
  return 0;
}
```

Algunas anotaciones:

La tabla `buff[]` se utiliza como si fuese una especie de tabla hash, me explico, para evitar tener que recorrer toda la cadena de caracteres a eliminar (en tu enunciado `X`) por cada caracter de la cadena fuente ( en tu enunciado `S`) se puede usar esta forma de indexación rápida. Esta pequeña tabla nos permite indexar usando directamente el propio valor del caracter (que no deja de ser un número). En la rutina inicial `reduce` se rellena esta tabla usando como fuente la cadena de caracteres que contiene los caracteres que se van a eliminar, de este modo, en la rutina recursiva sabemos siempre si tenemos que añadir el caracter de la cadena a limpiar en la cadena de salida `out` de una forma rápida.

Nos estamos aprovechando del simple hecho de que un `char` ocupa `1 byte` y por tanto tenemos un total de `2^8` números distintos, `0, 1, 2, 3, ...., 255`, valores que siempre se encuentran dentro de los límites del bloque de memoria apuntado por `buff`.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda y como fuente de aprendizaje.

Comment: Se agradece la respuesta pero no solemos responder preguntas que no tengan [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MrDave1999 Soy consciente de ello, es de hecho la primera pregunta que respondo sin que un OP muestre un mínimo de haberlo intentado, pero simplemente me apetecía ayudar.Gracias a ti por por recordar este tipo de cosas. Un saludo